# Как посчитать число цифр любого целого числа?

Tags: c, циклы, if, while

Что бы Вы изменили в нижеследующем коде (что не так, видно из скриншота внизу)?

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{
int N; 
int count=0; 
while (1)
{
printf ( "\nВведите число N: " ); 
scanf ( "%d", &N ); 
if (N==0)
printf("Вы ввели нуль\n");
while ( N > 0 || N<0) 
 { 
 N /= 10; 
 count ++;
 printf ( "В этом числе %d цифр\n", count );
 } 
getchar();
}
}
```

[image: число_цифр.png]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (N==0) 
{
  printf("Вы ввели нуль\n");
} 
else
{
  count = 0;
  while (N != 0) 
  { 
    N /= 10; 
    count++;
  } 
  printf("В этом числе %d цифр\n", count);
}
```

Comment: Прокомментировал Ваш вариант посредством скриншота ч/з правку вопроса...

Comment: @ОлегОстапчук кхм, кхм, ну обнулите `count` перед вычислением

Comment: Всё работает, рабочий код размещаю выше.

Comment: @ОлегОстапчук Не стоит править вопрос - в особенности если это 1. изменение на по сути другой вопрос (к счастью, не ваш случай) 2. изменение на правильный ответ. Судите сами - грубо говоря, к чему отвечающий старался и давал ответ на *правильный* код? :) Рабочий код разместил отвечающий, а комментировать, правя вопрос - и вовсе неверно. Поэтому вернул вопрос в его исходное состояние...